# XSLT for an XML document with arbitrary tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Just to clarify the title, I have an XML document that looks like the following:

```
<group>
  <starter>Start</starter>
  <backup1>Backup1</backup1>
</group>
<group>
  <starter>Another starter</starter>
  <backup1>Backup1</backup1>
  <backup2>Backup2</backup2>
  <backup3>Backup3</backup3>
  <reserve>Reserve</reserve>
</group>
```

So each group can have any number of `<backupN>` tags. I need to make sure my XSLT grabs all of them and renames them to "backup_n". Normally my XSLT would apply something in line with the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="group/backup">
```

and loop around that xpath selection. That clearly won't work as even if there is only 1 backup, it's still named `<backup1>` and there can also be an arbitrary amount of `<backupN>` tags.

What's the best way to loop around arbitrary tags like this? I am using XSLT 1.0, so can't really use any XSLT 2.0 greatness.

Comment: You have a document with ill-named elements (`<backup1>` through `<backupN>`) and want to transform it into another document with ill-named elements (`<backup_1>` through `<backup_N>`)? It you have the power, change it to `<backup num="1">` ... `<backup num="N">`, for the very reasons that made you ask this question. Equal elements should have equal names because things start to suck if they don't.

Comment: I'd love to - unfortunately I don't control the source of the XML. I am transforming it to JSON, I just need a way to grab the index so I can make the JSON more sensible.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't even mean to make you change the source, I only wanted to keep you from creating equally broken target XML. But since you transform to JSON, never mind. :) You can work with `position()` to grab the index, you don't have to look at the name "suffix" with `substring-after()`. You can, of course, but it's messier.

Comment: If I were transforming this to JSON I'd use an array for the backups, something like `{"starter":"Another starter", "backups":["Backup1", "Backup2", "Backup3"], "reserves":["Reserve"]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the elements whose name starts with `backup` you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="group/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'backup')]">
```

but depending on exactly what kind of output you're trying to produce it may be cleaner to do it in terms of template matching rather than `for-each`.

If you specifically want to restrict to elements whose name is "backup" followed by a number (excluding things like `backuptype`, for example) then you can add to the predicate

```
group/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'backup')
    and number(substring(local-name(), 7)) = number(substring(local-name(), 7))]
```

(this looks odd but the trick is that if `substring(local-name(), 7)` is not a valid number then the test becomes `NaN = NaN` which is always false - `NaN` does not equal anything, not even itself).

Comment: Ian, is there anyway to also get the index so I can retrieve `1` or `2` from `backup1` and `backup2`

Comment: @randombits within the `for-each` you can take a `substring` of the element's `local-name`, or you could use the `position()` function to get the current node's position within the list you selected.  This may not be the same as the trailing part of the element name, e.g. if the group had two backup elements named `backup2` and `backup5` then `position()` would still give you 1 and 2 whereas substring would give you 2 and 5.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful and well detailed answer. Will mark it as the right one as soon as SO allows me to.